# Wrap user's input (type or paste) with a span tag in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When users type or paste in a `contenteditable div`, how can I wrap what user typed (typing or paste) within a `span` tag.

I tried:

```
<div id="inputbox" style="border:1px solid lightgrey" contenteditable="true">

<script>
$(document).on('input', '#inputbox', function(e) {
    e.wrap('<span/>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this example

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>wrap demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  p {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 4px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hello</p>
<p>cruel</p>
<p>World</p>

<script>
$( "p" ).wrap( "<div></div>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the same just use the focus 

$( "input" ).focus(function() {
 your code wrap here
});

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
//you can change 'focusout' to 'input' to wrap the 'span' to each character the user types
$(document).on('focusout', '#inputbox', function(e) {

    $( this).contents().filter(function() {//contents will get all child elements including text nodes
      return this.nodeType === 3;//return only the text nodes in the matched element
    }).wrap('<span/>');

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't wrap the paste text, could you help me with this.

Comment: @zoyb It wraps the pasted texts when the DIV looses focus. What behavior are you looking for?